# Encryption with AES-256-GCM using (LibreSSL) libcrypto

Tags: c, aes, libcrypto, libressl

Given an appropriate `key` and `iv`, this C program should encrypt `stdin`, outputting to `stdout`.

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), key, iv);

const size_t block_size = 128;
unsigned char inbuf[block_size];
unsigned char outbuf[block_size + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
int inlen, outlen;
for (;;)
{
        inlen = fread(inbuf, 1, block_size, stdin);
        if (inlen <= 0)
                break;

        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen)
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, stdout);
}
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &outlen)
fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, stdout);
```

(Error checking removed for brevity.)

I am verifying the output of this code by running

`openssl aes-256-gcm -in ciphertext.txt -K <key> -iv <iv> -d`

This successfully and reliably decrypts the ciphertext, but writes **bad decrypt** afterwards, for instance

```
$ openssl aes-256-gcm ...
Hello World.
bad decrypt
```

What could be going wrong to cause it to say this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was completely failing to get the GCM authentication tag after encryption and then providing it during decryption.

The "bad decrypt" message was misleading — the decryption was going fine, but the tag providing authentication was not provided.

The tag can be gotten at **after** the call to `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` with

```
unsigned char *tag = malloc(TAGSIZE);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, TAGSIZE, tag);
```

`TAGSIZE` is the size in bytes of the tag, and may be a number of different values. This is discussed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Security) among other places.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is, that you do not implement proper padding as PKCS#7 requires. `openssl` expects correct padding to be present in the decoded message. Rules are:

- There has to be *always* at least 1 byte of padding
- It has to be padded to block size of the cipher

Now with AES-256 you have a block size of 128 bit (16 byte). This means, you have to add 1-16 padding bytes. The padding bytes to add are always the *size* of the padding, so if you have to add 9 bytes of padding, you would add 9 `0x09` bytes.

If you properly add this padding to your original plaintext, then openssl should stop complaining on decrypt.

Comment: The OP is asking about AES-256-**GCM** which includes zero padding, PKCS#7 padding is not used with GCM mode. See [GCM padding or not?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42412/gcm-padding-or-not) and [Galois/Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode)

Comment: Oh my, it looks like we are stuck with an answer that is wrong. **Sad!**